# bad return type in method reference: java.util.function.Predicate

Tags: java, predicate

The my below Java 8 test code is complaining. My understanding is that, return type of the *valid* method is a Predicate which evaluates to Boolean and filter method in Stream also expects the Predicate. Is my understanding is wrong? Can anyone help me to fix this error

```
*public class Main{
    public static void main(String... args){

    Stream.of("12/31/2014",
              "01-01-2015",
              2016").filter(Main::valid).forEach(s ->
                                              out.println(s));   
   }
   public static Predicate<Boolean> valid(String dt){
     return p->dt.length()>0;   
   } 
}*
```

**ERROR: incompatible types: bad return type in method reference
    java.util.function.Predicate cannot be converted to boolean**

JDK: 1.8.0_102
 IDE: IntelliJ IDEA - 2017.2.5 Community Edition

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your method should return a boolean, not a predicate. `Main::valid` already is the predicate. Also, you'd then just do `return dt.length() > 0` then.

Comment: I wanted to return the Predicate

Comment: If you'd return the predicate you'd have to call the method that returns it directly and since the predicate gets the value when being called, the method that returns it, doesn't need such a value. The method to build a predicate would then look like this: `Predicate<String> buildPredicate() {  return s->s.length()>0; }` and then call it like `...filter( buildPredicate() )...` (this is meant to match your style, normally you'd rather just do `...filter( s -> s.length() > 0)...`).

Comment: Note well that `Predicate<Boolean>` designates a predicate that can be evaluated for an *input* of type `Boolean`.  The type argument has nothing to do with the result of evaluating a `Predicate` (via its `test()` method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`valid` return type is `Predicate<Boolean>` but `filter` waits a lambda whose return type is `boolean`. So it should looks like (not sure it corresponds to your initial intent):

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String... args){

    Stream.of("12/31/2014", "01-01-2015", "2016")
          .filter(Main::valid)
          .forEach(s ->out.println(s));   
   }
   public static boolean valid(String dt){
     return dt.length()>0;   
   } 
}
```

where you filter the stream with the `valid` function.

Before using method reference, just try to write the lambda you need to filter. The stream before `filter` is of type `Stream<String>` so the lambda must takes a `String` and return a `boolean` (this is required for any `Predicate`). So it may looks like:

```
Stream.of("12/31/2014", "01-01-2015", "2016")
      .filter(s -> s.length()>0)
```

Now you can try to find an existing function that exactly do the job, say it is `valid`, then you can replace the call with `.filter(Main::valid)`.

Now if you have a method that returns you a `Predicate<String>` (because your actual stream injects `String`s into the predicate) you can write:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String... args){

    Stream.of("12/31/2014", "01-01-2015", "2016")
          .filter(Main::valid())
          .forEach(s->out.println(s));   
   }
   public static Predicate<String> valid(){
     return s->s.length()>0;   
   } 
}
```

where you inject to filter the predicate constructed by a call to `valid`.